# Error in check.length("fill") : 'gpar' element 'fill' must not be length 0

Tags: r, pheatmap

I faced a very weird error, possibly a bug in `R 3.5.1` or `pheatmap`

The following code is working fine:

```
rownames(df) <- colnames(mat)
xx <- pheatmap(mat, annotation_col=df)
```

But the following is not working:

```
rownames(df) <- str_sub(colnames(mat), 1, -3)
xx <- pheatmap(mat, annotation_col=df)
```

Everything just looks perfect, but it is giving the error:

> Error in check.length("fill") : 
>     'gpar' element 'fill' must not be length 0

I reloaded `Rstudio` but the problem persists. Any modifications of `rownames` of `df` makes it impossible to draw the chart. I tried also `substr` function.
Does anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: Can you please make your example reproducible by including sample data for `df` and `mat`.

Comment: Have you changed the column names of 'mat' with `colnames(mat) <- str_sub(colnames(mat), 1, -3)`

Comment: Yes, you are right, that was the issue: I did not

Answer (score 14):

The issue was that `colnames(mat)` should be matched with `rownames(df)`, and so I am not allowed to just modify one without the other. The following code worked:

```
colnames(mat) <- str_sub(colnames(mat), 1, -3)
rownames(df) <- colnames(mat)
xx <- pheatmap(mat, annotation_col=df)
```